# How can we debug Entity framework core dbcontextPooling in c#

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I want to check how DbcontextPooling is working internally and want to debug that, is there any way I will achieve that ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Entity framework core](https://nuget.info/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/6.0.7) has [source link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/sourcelink) enabled. This means you can debug the EF code just like your code. You can step into any EF method from visual studio.

Assuming you have `AddDbContextPool` somewhere in your code, you can step into this call, add breakpoints.